# JOLT Spec to build arrays from group of similarly named keys

Tags: json, jolt

Trying to build a JOLT spec to put similarly named keys into an array, and strip off leading 6 characters.  In below example, all keys starting with "fd1lk1" would go into array "Link1", keys starting with "fd1lk2" would go into array "Link2", etc.

Thanks for any help!

Source JSON:

```
{
  "EventName": "WidgetFeedImpression",
  "WidgetName": "_blah_2019.08.17",
  "WidgetID": "5d56ef313db7c300018d9c66",
  "WidgetVariationName": "_blah_2019.08.17",
  "WidgetVariationID": "5b5f524eb1932300014d0928",
  "WidgetTemplate": "blah-six-grid-wth-image",
  "fd1lk1Title": "link 1 title",
  "fd1lk1Image": "link 1 image",
  "fd1lk1TargetURL": "link 1 url",
  "fd1lk1Position": "1",
  "fd1lk1Id": "fd5da8ce0f8701a3000190efbdlk1",
  "fd1lk2Title": "link 2 title",
  "fd1lk2Image": "link 2 image",
  "fd1lk2TargetURL": "link 2 url",
  "fd1lk2Position": "2",
  "fd1lk2Id": "fd5da8ce0f8701a3000190efbdlk2",
  "gtmcb": "1878625665",
  "CreatedAtUtc": "2019-10-24T16:57:01.5274702Z"
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{
  "EventName": "WidgetFeedImpression",
  "WidgetName": "_blah_2019.08.17",
  "WidgetID": "5d56ef313db7c300018d9c66",
  "WidgetVariationName": "_blah_2019.08.17",
  "WidgetVariationID": "5b5f524eb1932300014d0928",
  "WidgetTemplate": "blah-six-grid-wth-image",
  "Link1" : [ {
    "Title" : "link 1 title",
    "Image" : "link 1 image",
    "TargetURL" : "link 1 url",
    "Position" : "1",
    "Id" : "fd5da8ce0f8701a3000190efbdlk1"
  } ],
  "Link2" : [ {
    "Title" : "link 2 title",
    "Image" : "link 2 image",
    "TargetURL" : "link 2 url",
    "Position" : "2",
    "Id" : "fd5da8ce0f8701a3000190efbdlk2"
  } ],
  "gtmcb": "1878625665",
  "CreatedAtUtc": "2019-10-24T16:57:01.5274702Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` in `fd1lk*Title` is extracted and used with `&(0,1)`:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "fd1lk*Title": "Link&(0,1).[0].Title",
      "fd1lk*Image": "Link&(0,1).[0].Image",
      "fd1lk*TargetURL": "Link&(0,1).[0].TargetURL",
      "fd1lk*Position": "Link&(0,1).[0].Position",
      "fd1lk*Id": "Link&(0,1).[0].Id",
      "*": {
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

See [here](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#prefixSoupToBuckets) for the basic concept.